# Xcode keeps committing DerivedData folder

Tags: git, xcode4

How do I remove the DerivedData folder from my Xcode's repo, and how do I permanently prevent it from including it in the commits?

Xcode 3 didn't have this problem.  Started with Xcode 4.1.

### Solution

`git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch DerivedData/'` (for folders)

`git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename_here'` (for files)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, one thing to make note of is that it goes through all the commit history and remakes them which results in the git history repeating itself which is a little annoying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to remove the folder from your previous history you can follow [Github's](http://help.github.com/remove-sensitive-data/) guide to removing sensitive data.

If you just want to remove it from here on out, you can remove it from the repo with
 `git rm -r  --cached folderName/` 
Then, add the following line to a file called `.gitignore` in your root directory
`folderName`

Comment: Nope.  Still keeps saying didn't match any files.  But I see the commits in the Xcode repo..

Comment: Are you sure they are in there?  If you do `git ls-files`. Does it show the files in the DerivedData folder?

Comment: It doesn't.  But, when I show Xcode's version, it shows them a deleted.  (I deleted the DerivedData folder and moved it to default location.  Now it's showing them as D.  But, all the old changes are still in the repo.  I can browse all of the previous changes.  Basically, I see them when I look in the "history" part of the Xcode repo.  I can also view all changes... which means they're still in the repo.

Comment: If you want to remove them as if they never existed in your repo, follow the github guide I linked.  But git is no longer tracking them if they aren't in `git ls-files`.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your derived data repo? It's usually on ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
It shouldn't automatically get committed unless you override this default location.

Comment: I put my DerivedData info my project's folder.  Is there a way to remove the folder form the git's commits and to ignore it in the future?

Comment: Yes, you need a .gitignore file. A sample template here https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Objective-C.gitignore You can read more about gitignore here http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html

Comment: But how do I remove the already cached DerivedData from my repo? I'm trying `git rm --cached DerivedData` but it's saying `DerivedData' did not match any files`

Comment: Dont' use --cached. It's for removing from the index. If it says there is no matching files, there is probably not. Are you sure you added it to repo?

Comment: `--cached` will remove it from the index, but not the working dir.  I don't know what that folder is for, but if you want to keep the folder around, just not tracking it, use `--cached`.  if you you want to delete the folder, leave it off.

Comment: Positive.  I'm looking at the Repo with Xcode and it's showing my all of the DerivedData along with comments and changes.